# Android: portrait and landscape designe issue

Tags: java, android, xml, landscape-portrait

so as stated in the title, I have an issue with the different designes between landscape and portrait, I have been trying to make landscape look better(more like the portrait design) but no matter what I do it turns out ugly(small imageview and smaller movie details field), here is the picture of the looks and the xml code, if there is anything that can be done id love to hear you're advice.

[image]

XML CODE (codes are pretty much the same):

this one is inside layout-land

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F0FFF0"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10.0" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        android:paddingRight="100dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/movie_title"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" 
            />

                <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvError3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6.0"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etBody"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/movie_body"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        android:paddingRight="100dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etUrl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/movie_url"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bShow"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_black_glossy"
            android:text="@string/show_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvError"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivMovieImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bSave" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSave"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/space"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_black_glossy"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"
            android:text="@string/save" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bCancel"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bSave"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_black_glossy"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/space"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

this one is inside standart layout folder (serves as portrait)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F0FFF0"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10.0" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/movie_title"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" 
            />

                <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvError3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6.0"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etBody"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/movie_body"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etUrl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/movie_url"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bShow"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_black_glossy"
            android:text="@string/show_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvError"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4.0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivMovieImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bSave" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSave"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/space"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_black_glossy"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:text="@string/save" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bCancel"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bSave"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_black_glossy"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/space"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using your horizontal space more-  take the picture of the movie and make it full height to the right of the screen, with all of the text to the left of it

Comment: Good advice, but the problem is that I am requested to keep the landscape same design as the portrait is.

Comment: Can you put the whole thing in a scrollview so that you can have larger text boxes and need to scroll down to get to the buttons?  I'd rather have larger text and scroll than fit on the screen but get 2 lines of text.  If you can't change the layout that's the best advice I can give.  The problem isn't the xml, its the layout needs more vertical pixels.

Comment: Awesome, can you help alittle with the scrollview thingy? how to define it exactly?

Comment: Just put a ScrollView around what's currently your top level layout class.  That should be enough to see if you like the effect.  A ScrollView has a single child and takes care of scrolling it vertically for you